# How to simulate ACPI events in virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, acpi

I'm intending to work on a Python script that will poll ACPI events, specifically - the lid close event. Of course, flipping lid on and off on my laptop isn't the best approach, and essentially impossible on desktop setups. At the same time, I do have to use Virtual Box since my host system has different desktop than what I intend to target ( Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME ). Hence the question - how do I trigger ACPI events in Virtual Box guest OS  ?

Comment: Does this help: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changeacpicust

Comment: @noeppinoeppi  No, doesn't seem to address my question. I am guessing it might be useful at some point if I want to copy ACPI table from real laptop to virtual machine, but it doesn't address triggering the lid event and it's nowhere confirmed it's the right way. So I'll just say so far this doesn't seem fully relevant.

Comment: [This may help you](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=52974), specially the part about enabling  acpi and the `vbht`. [This seems to be repo](https://github.com/mariano-perez-rodriguez/vbht) with some scripts to trigger acpi events.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I think that lid switch events are communicated to userspace via an evdev input device. At least on my laptop, there is a dedicated lid switch device in /dev/input. When I grab it, systemd won't detect any lid switch changes, so I guess it's the only thing that is monitored. That device can probably be faked by a uinput device (e.g. using python-evdev). No solution for your problem, but maybe a workaround.